# initial load includes all existing data from Room DB

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

I have implemented pagination to cache my data into a room db and create a flow to load data from the db (as discribed here: [Page from network and database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db#basic-usage))

I also added a custom paging source, which is pretty much the same as the default ([LimitOffsetPagingSource](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/room/room-paging/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/paging/LimitOffsetPagingSource.kt)) PagingSource with few extra data modifications.

Basically everything works fine, except the very first data collection of the paging flow. When there are already data in the room db, `collectLatest` collects all existing data which are currently in the database.
After that my remote mediator immediately clears the database and everthing works normal, but the db reset comes too late for the first data collection.

My RecyclerView isn't nested in any other scrollable view but `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Here is the log output of PagingSource, RemoteMediator and the size of the adapter snapshot:
[image]

Does anyone know, why all the data get collected, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I realized, that the adapter gets filled with `null` placeholders to match the current size of the table. So, this should be a correct behaviour and nothing to worry :D